# Google map not showing in thymeleaf

Tags: google-maps, thymeleaf

I'm trying to load a google map within a thymeleaf page:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        var map;
        function initMap() {
          console.log('initMap');
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
         });
       }
    </script>
    <script th:inline="javascript" async="async" defer="defer" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apiKey&callBack=initMap"></script>              
    <div id="map" style="width:200px; height: 200px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"></div>
 </div>
```

Note: the html is a thymeleaf fragment.

Webdeveloper console does not show any error.
The console output within the callback method is also not printed.

What can i do, where might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved:

1. callBack has a spelling issue, it must be called "callback" (in lowercase)
2. the container div "map" must be placed befor initMap funtion.

Now it works.